# New Domian Server and New Exchange Server with Issue installing Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016, windows-server-2019

I created a whole new Domain Server 2019 and have an Exchange Server 2019 and trying to install Exchange with the install Wizard and am stopped at 8 of 14.

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
                    $agentName = "Mobile Message Receive Agent";
                    $agent = get-transportagent -Identity:$agentName;
                    if ($agent) {
                    uninstall-transportagent -Identity:$agentName;
                    };
                " was run: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Extensibility, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Extensibility, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.AgentTasks.GetTransportAgent.InternalProcessRecord()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.<ProcessRecord>b__91_1()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.InvokeRetryableFunc(String funcName, Action func, Boolean terminatePipelineIfFailed)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.ProcessTaskStage(TaskStage taskStage, Action initFunc, Action mainFunc, Action completeFunc)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.Task.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
".
```

Comment: Thoroughly verify all the prerequisites. E. g. dotnet and vc++ versions.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/plan-and-deploy/prerequisites?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: Yeah I think @Vadim is probably right, you're missing a pre-requisite. Also make sure that you aren't trying to install Exchange on a Domain Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error info below, I suspect that the installation package lost the file named 'Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Extensibility'. Please have a try that redownloading the package and installing again.

"System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Extensibility, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."